# Неожиданный вылет программы после успешного выполнения кода

Tags: java, android, tcp

Недавно стал увлекаться java.
И решил написать простую программу по получению расписания с колледжа.

Дизайн все сделал, реализовал сервер на python(Не ругайте)
И на java реализовал отправку пакета с данными логин и пароль.

Редактор кода ошибок не выдает

Код клиента:

```
package com.example.oneproject;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

import java.net.Socket;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        EditText login = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login);
        EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        Button auth = (Button) findViewById(R.id.auth);

        auth.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                t1.start();
            }

            Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Socket clientSocket = new Socket("тут нгрок", 18273);
                        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new 
OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream()));
                        String outMsg = "";
                        outMsg = login.getText() + ":" + password.getText();
                        out.write(outMsg);
                        out.flush();
                        out.close();
                        clientSocket.close();
                        login.setText("Received Data: " + out);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        login.setText("Ошибка " + e);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Пытался решить проблему вынесением в поток другим методом, но не получилось.
Много гуглил но не смог найти ничего на подобную тему.
Заранее спасибо большое если поможете мне.

Данные успешно доходят

[image: Логи сервера]

После успешной отправки данных клиент просто вылетает

Comment: Если вылетает - в логах должна быть причина в виде красных строк с ошибкой и указанием на конкретную строку. Скорее всего вылетает тут: `login.setText(` - вы пытаетесь не на главном потоке трогать вьюхи. Попробуйте их как-то так обернуть: `runOnUiThread { login.setText() }`

Comment: дело в том что я запускаю в эмуляторе андроида блустак, на моем процессоре не устанавливается драйвер для создания устройства прямо в студии. В редакторе кода нет красных точек и ошибок

Comment: У вас есть коннект студии с виртуальным девайсом блюстакса? Если есть смотрите в [LogCat](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat#running), если нет - включите поддержку ADB в блюстаксе. Без лога ошибки никто вам не сможет сказать в чём проблема, а с логом вполне вероятно вы и сами сможете найти её

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы меняете текст в виджете из фонового потока - менять UI можно только в главном. Перебросьте эту задачу в главный поток, например так:

```java
runOnUiThread(() -> login.setText("Received Data: " + out));
```